# How can I change the img src value in another element once a certain image is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

when a html element is clicked i want the data attribute of that element to to be displayed correctly, in this case an image. in this case i want it that when ken is clicked the image in his data-fighter attribute replaces the current image in the div.portrait which is ryup.png.

```
var name = $("#name");
var nation = $("#nation");
var style = $("#style");
var fighter = $("div.portrait img");



$("[data-name], [data-nation], [data-style], [data-     
fighter]").click(function(){
name.html($(this).data().name);
nation.html($(this).data().nation);
style.html($(this).data().style);
// something needs to go here
}); 


<div class="portrait">
<img src="images/ryup.png" alt="Ryu" title="Ryu">
</div>

<img src="images/kens.png" alt="Ken" title="Ken" data-name=" Ken Masters"
data-nation=" American" 
data-style=" Ansatsuken" 
data-fighter="images/kenp.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/kh51qnd3/1/)**.

Then you should replace the `src` attribute like :

```
fighter.prop('src', $(this).data('fighter'));
```

```js
$("[data-name], [data-nation], [data-style], [data-fighter]").click(function() {
  var name = $("#name");
  var nation = $("#nation");
  var style = $("#style");
  var fighter = $("div.portrait img");

  name.html($(this).data().name);
  nation.html($(this).data().nation);
  style.html($(this).data().style);
  fighter.prop('src', $(this).data('fighter'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portrait">
  <img src="https://www.ssbwiki.com/images/thumb/3/32/Link_SSB4.png/100px-Link_SSB4.png" alt="Ryu" title="Ryu">
</div>

<img src="https://www.ssbwiki.com/images/thumb/6/63/Ryu_SSB4.png/100px-Ryu_SSB4.png" alt="Ken" title="Ken" data-name=" Ken Masters" data-nation=" American" data-style=" Ansatsuken" data-fighter="https://www.ssbwiki.com/images/thumb/6/63/Ryu_SSB4.png/100px-Ryu_SSB4.png">
```